# Finding date between start date and end date

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to check whether a date is between start date and end date.

i have added a where clause

```
where datepaid between '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-15'
```

but the problem is that it excludes '2010-04-15'.

It should include end date also how can i do this?

Please help me on this

Regards,

pankaj

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify the time parts explicitly:

```
WHERE datepaid BETWEEN '2010-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-04-15 23:59:59'
```

Comment: does it include like 2010-04-15 23:59:59.56?

Comment: @Jens: As far as I'm aware, MySQL doesn't store fractional seconds. If it does support them then I'd change the clause to something like `BETWEEN '2010-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2010-04-15 23:59:59.999'` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps your dates include intraday times. Try this instead:

```
where '2010-04-01' <= datepaid AND datepaid < '2010-04-16'
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying that means i have to add 1 day interval to the end date to fetch the correct record

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE   datepaid >= '2010-04-01'
        AND datepaid < '2010-04-15' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
where datepaid between '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-15 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to dates having time:

```
select
    '2010-04-15' between '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-15', -- 1
    '2010-04-15 12:00:00' between '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-15', -- 0
    '2010-04-15 12:00:00' between '2010-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-04-15 23:59:59' -- 1
```

Either add time to range delimiters or truncate values before comparison:

```
select
    '2010-04-15 12:00:00' between '2010-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2010-04-15 23:59:59' -- 1
    cast('2010-04-15 12:00:00' as date) between '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-15' -- 1
```

I haven't checked but I suppose performance is better without casting.

Answer (score 0):

where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),datepaid,23) between '2010-04-01' AND '2010-04-15'

Answer (score -1):

add this clause:

```
OR datepaid = '2010-04-15'
```

Comment: This won't do anything. The `BETWEEN` clause already covers this case.