# how to select between two dates

Tags: sql

I want to use this query and select the data from `1/1/2019` to `7/2/2019`

```
SELECT fdp.PARENT_CASEID, fdp.POLICYNUMBER, p.WFSTATE, fdp.OWNERNAME, fdp.INSUREDNAME, p.WFLOCKTYPE, p.WFLOCKUSER, p.WORKFLOWID, p.WFWORKITEMID, p.WFROUTINGTICKETID, p.WFWORKSTEPNAME , p.WFWORKSTEPNAME , p.WFSTEPENTRYTIME, fdr.PENDINGREQUIREMENTSREASON, fdCI.NEWUNDERWRITINGUSER,c.ACL,p.WFSTEPENTRYTIME,p.WFFLOWENTRYTIME

FROM PINewBusiness p 
   JOIN FDPolicyDetails fdp 
      ON SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY,{{system.CFPolicyRKLen,raw}},LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = fdp.PARENT_CASEID
   JOIN FDRounting fdr 
      ON SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY,{{system.CFPolicyRKLen,raw}},LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = fdr.PARENT_CASEID and p.WFWORKSTEPNAME = 'PendingRequirements'
   JOIN FDCaseInformation fdCI 
      ON fdCI.PARENT_CASEID =  fdP.PARENT_CASEID
   JOIN CFPolicyCaseFolder c 
      ON SUBSTRING(p.CFREPKEY,{{system.CFPolicyRKLen,raw}},LEN(p.CFREPKEY)) = c.CASEFOLDERID
```

Comment: You need to specify (a) what DBMS you are using (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL etc.) and (b) what is your date variable for this to be answerable

Comment: Which one is the column including date information and what is the type of this column (varchar or datetime?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding date between start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644373/finding-date-between-start-date-and-end-date)

Comment: Dear @AlMadi as I found a lot of your SQL-questions are for MySQL this question is already answered: [Finding date between start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644373/finding-date-between-start-date-and-end-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|304.4573)

Comment: Btw p.Stepentrytime is selected twice...for reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #temp2 (id int, mydatecolumn datetime)
insert into #temp2 values (1,'2019-01-01')
insert into #temp2 values (2,'2019-02-07')
```

Assuming "mydatecolumn" is your column name, and the data type of this column is datetime, as above, then you can use:

```
declare @fromDate datetime = '2019-01-01'
declare @endDate datetime = '2019-02-07'

select ...
from ...
join ...
where mydatecolumn between @fromDate and @EndDate
```

OR

```
where mydatecolumn >= @fromDate and mydatecolumn <= @endDate
```

If the datatype of your "mydatecolumn" is actually varchar, then you need to use casting first:

```
create table #temp3 (id int, datetim varchar(50))
insert into #temp3 values (1,'2019-01-01')
insert into #temp3 values (2,'2019-02-07')

declare @fromDate datetime = '2019-01-01'
declare @endDate datetime = '2019-02-07'

select * from #temp3 where datetim between cast(@fromDate as DATE) and cast(@endDate as date)
```

If you are getting @fromDate and @endDate as varchar at the beginning, then no need to cast anymore, but make sure the texts are exactly equal while doing the comparison.

This answer works for SQL Server.

If this answer does not help you, then I appreciate if you add data types and example data to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this condition at the end of your query :

```
where date_column >= '1/1/2019' and date_column <= '7/2/2019';
```

let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `between` operator in the where clause.

```
where date_column between '1/1/2019' and '7/2/2019'
```

Comment: Try `select '5/2/2019' between '2/2/2019' and '10/2/2019'` and you'll see this doesn't work...